# do something after asp Hyperlink navigationUrl from usercontrol in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i want to change something like a small code after navigationUrl happened in asp.net Hyperlink
how can i do it in usercontrol?
and this is my hyperlink code

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkLogin" runat="server" CssClass="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" Text="Login" NavigateUrl="~/Login.aspx" />
```

and i can't use linkButton
With Respect

Comment: What is the `something` you're trying to do?  This will likely dictate the recommendations you're given.

Comment: as i said a code for example change css style,  lnkLogin.CssStyle="my css" but i don't know how to do it when navigationUrl happened

Answer (score 0):

After the NavigationUrl happens, you'll be on your Login.aspx page.  If you cannot use a `LinkButton`, you'll need to handle it with the `IsPostBack` property, perhaps additionally checking for criteria in the querystring.

```
if(!IsPostBack){
    lnkLogin.CssStyle="my css";
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer,  but where should i use this PostBack in the login page? and what PostBack doing?

Comment: Yes, in the login page.  `IsPostBack` checks to see if a `Button`, `LinkButton` or `ImageButton` was clicked, or if a `Checkbox` check changed or `DropDownList` selected index changed - or a number of other different events.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkLogin" runat="server" CssClass="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" Text="Login" NavigateUrl="~/Login.aspx" onclick="changeLoginCssClass();" />

function changeLoginCssClass{
$("#lnkLogin").removeClass("blue");
 $("#lnkLogin").addClass("red");
});
```